# CentOS Mirror Update Just One File

Tags: centos, repository, mirror

I host a local mirror of Centos5 and Cento6 to run updates of our servers.  I do not update them regularly, though, to provide a stable environment for our production servers.  However there are times when I would like to update one specific package (like Bash right now).  I have the new RPMs in the proper folder, but when I run `yum update` on one of my servers, even after a `yum clean all`.  I'm guessing yum uses the `repomd.xml` file to determine whether anything needs updated, I haven't had any luck so far.

Does anyone know how to get the yum repo to reflect the new RPMs I have added in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the metadata. In the dir with the RPMS for example run

```
 createrepo .
```

Comment: Yes! That works.  For the record, I ran it within the RPMS directory and that didn't work.  It re-creates the `repodata` folder, so I needed to go up one directory for it to work correctly.  It takes a while to run, too.

Comment: for which dir you run it in depends on how your yum repo file is setup